# Magento 2 upgrade - Setup:upgrade stuck at Magento_Customer

Tags: php, magento, magento2

I am trying to upgrade Magento 2.4.3 to Magento 2.4.3-p1 using composer and successfully new version upgrade but when run upgrade command but process stuck not progress process of from Data install/update Magento_Customer.

Also, not showing any error in the error log and apache2 error log, I have tried all possibility but it's last stuck in Magento_Customer